# How to pass different Content-Type when in intercepet we put content type = 'Content-Type': 'application/json',

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular7

so in my all API request we're sending `'Content-Type': 'application/json',`

but in special case when file upload we need to send conent-type : `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;`

otherwise we're getting error like :

```
message: "Unable to translate bytes [83] at index 152 from specified code page to Unicode."
```

we create interceptor, is there anyway to override interceptor content type- how do you handle in your project? or any suggestion?

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({

      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
          headers = headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
        }
      }
    }
const cloneReq = req.clone({ headers });
```

Comment: If its only for some particular url, check the req.url if it matches your required url then create new header with the required content-type else pass the same header with content-type application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this . Try to check the URL and if it matches your fileupload's URL then create header with different content-type for that call.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
    // Set different header in case of file upload URL
    if(req.url && req.url.indexOf("fileupload") !== -1) {
        headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        });
    }
}
const cloneReq = req.clone({ headers });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question It feels you want to conditionally add headers to your request. You can do this by `cloning` and adding a `new set of headers`

```
intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if(specialCondition){
      const modifiedReq= req.clone({
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${accessToken}'
      })
    });
   return next.handle(modifiedReq);
}    
  return next.handle(req);
}
```

The `specialCondition` needs to come from your based on the requirement like a specific `URL` or anything similar.